# Extract JSON object from HTML attribute

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

I'm building dynamically with `JavaScript` a `HTML` page and setting an attribute with a text.
Sometimes the text is a simple string and sometimes I have a JSON Object that I use `JSON.stringify()` to save it as a string.

```
 $("<a id=\"ftr\" myData=\"" + myString + "\" </a>").appendTo(myDiv);
```

And after that I extracting this attribute:

`var temp = $(this).attr("myData");  // inside loop , $(this) refers to the correct link`

When it's a simple text like this, everything works fine.

```
 <a id="ftr" myData="text test"></a>
```

But when extracting JSON object I get as a result only : `"[{"`

```
 <a id="ftr" myData="[{"text":"test1","link":"http:\\www.google.com"},{"text":"test2","url":"http:www.google.com"}]></a>
```

How can I extract the full object in `JSON` format?

Answer (score 2):

Use quotes properly

```
<a id="ftr" myData='[{"text":"test1","link":"http:\\www.google.com"},{"text":"test2","url":"http:www.google.com"}]'></a>
```

Also I would suggest you to use data-* attributes like

```
<a id="ftr" data-mydata='[{"text":"test1","link":"http:\\www.google.com"},{"text":"test2","url":"http:www.google.com"}]'></a>
```

Then you can fetch using [.data()](http://api.jquery.com/data/)

```
var temp = $(this).data("mydata");
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/satpalsingh/6ESLw/)

Answer (score 0):

Quotations fixed

```
  <a id="ftr" myData="[{'text':'test1','link':'http:\\www.google.com'},{'text':'test2','url':'http:www.google.com'}]></a>
```

Answer (score 0):

Well, one option is very simple: your code isn't working because you the double quotes in the JSON string close the HTML attribute value. So you could use single quotes in the HTML instead. (The other problem is that you never close the `a` tag.)

```
$('<a id=\'ftr\' myData=\'' + myString + '\'></a>').appendTo(myDiv);
```

***DO NOT DO THIS***

A far superior option is to stop serialising the data to JSON. You don't need to. jQuery has a fantastic data-storage functionality using the [`$.fn.data`](http://api.jquery.com/data) function, which can store complex data natively:

```
$("<a id=\"ftr\" />").data({data: dataObject}).appendTo(myDiv);
```

You can then access the data with the `data` function again:

```
$('#ftr').data('data')[0].link; // returns "http:\\www.google.com"
```

Comment: One other note: backslashes are used for escaping, so the string would actually be `http:\www.google.com`. And URLs use forward slashes anyway. This is irrelevant to your question, but may crop up as a problem for you down the line!